# How is a process waken up if slept in interruptible state?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, scheduling, preemption

The kernel code can explicitly put the process to sleep if it's waiting for some task to occur. Now, if the task is put in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state, it can wake either by explicit wake up call or by receiving a signal.

1. Let's say another process issued a signal to a process which is in the wait queue and in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state, it will put the process into `TASK_RUNNING` and the signal will be handled when the process is scheduled next. Is this correct?
2. An explicit wake up call by other process can also be used to wake up the slept processes. I am wondering how could another process know when the condition became true for the slept process to wake up? Suppose a disk i/o is to be completed and so the process is put to sleep. How could another process know that the i/o is completed? Or is it done by kernel threads?
   What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is up to the code that entered the interruptible state to detect the interruption and take appropriate action when it wakes. That might involve the code that is currently handling the user operation completing it with a `-ERESTARTSYS` error that will be intercepted and dealt with before the system call returns to user mode.
2. The code that has completed some I/O can just issue a "wake up" to the queue it is responsible for without caring whether there is any task on the queue to be woken up, or the exact condition the task is waiting for.

   The task that is woken up needs to decide what to do, and that could include repeating the wait if the the condition it is waiting for had not been satisfied.

Comment: When is a signal checked and signal handler called? I am guessing on return from system calls and interrupts, right? Now, if a process sends a signal to the slept process in interruptible state, it gets waken up. However, the process checks signal only on system call returns. How does the now-waken-up process respond to the signal received? Also, if the resource gets available, will it perform its i/o operation which was blocked or respond to the signal?

Comment: @LuciferPoltergeist Yes, pending signals will be handled before the syscall returns to user mode, or the system call might be restarted after returning from the signal handler. It's up the the code what it does when woken up, but the expectation is that it should not continue a blocking operation if a signal is pending. It does not necessarily need to return an error. For example, a blocking read or write file operation could return a partial, non-zero amount, and only return an error if no data has been transferred.